# What means ''ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'33.4904

Tags: python, import

[image]When i import a obj file this error pops up and idk how to fix it somebody know how?

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'33.4904\xb1'
```

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not images. Ideally by using ``` (3 backticks), then on the next line(s) the error message, then add another empty line and put another triple backtick ``` there. And then I think you need another empty line to make it work.

Comment: Looks like it's a ± character causing the issue: [Unicode Character 'PLUS-MINUS SIGN' (U+00B1)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b1/index.htm)